# using delegate to call a function of the invoker ViewController gives error in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I have a `UIViewController` `Class Aplha` that calls another `UIViewController` `Class Beta` in a modalView.
In `Alpha.h`, I declared a function:

```
-(void)selectMyImage:(NSString *)myImage;
```

In Aplha.m:

```
#import "Beta.h"

-(IBAction)clickMe:(id)sender
{
    Beta *b=[[Beta alloc]initWithNibName:@"Beta" bundle:nil];
    b.delegate=self;
    [self presentModalViewController:b animated:YES];
}
```

The above code shows the ViewCOntroller in modal view. I have an `id delegate;` declared in my `Beta.h`. Now when i try to call the function of `Alpha` from `Beta` class, it gives me error.
Here is my code in `Beta.m`:

```
 -(void)callAlpha
 {
     [delegate selectMyImage:imagename]; //imagename is declared in Beta.h too.
 }
```

The Xcode shows the red error mark saying `"No known instance method for selector 'mySelectedImage:'"`

In iOS 4.x SDK it runs fine. and Here I have **enabled the ARC** also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the type `id` has no method named `-mySelectedImage:`. It's customary to create a protocol for your delegates and declare the delegate as following that protocol:

```
// Declared somewhere that both Alpha and Beta can see
@protocol BetaDelegate
- (void)selectMyImage:(NSString*)imageName;
@end

// Alpha.h
@interface Alpha : UIViewController <BetaDelegate>
 // rest of alpha decls
@end

// Beta.h
@interface Beta : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic,weak) id<BetaDelegate> delegate;
  // rest of beta decls
@end
```

If this seems like too much work for something only you're working on or whatever, you can also just specifically declare the delegate as being of class `Alpha`, then the compiler will be able to see that `Alpha` actually declares that method.

Comment: what did you mean by "declare somewhere that both alpha and beta can see"??

Comment: i am getting a warning at line "b.delegate=self" saying "passing 'Alpha *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<BetaDelegate>'"